# What word describes keeping something for purposes of reference, and tracking history?

Tags: single-word-requests

Context: At a Town council meeting, one policy was rescinded, and a new policy was presented. One councillor requested that a record be kept of the old policy for reference so the new policy could be better understood. Like a breadcrumb trail, so people who read the new policy could know where it came from and how it evolved.

I'm trying to fill in the blank:

> Councillor [...] requested that the intent of the *old policy* be preserved in
>   the *new policy* for _________ purposes...

Comment: I would say *...for the purposes of historical record*.

Comment: I'm considering, "Councillor [...] requested that a *vestige* of the old policy be preserved in the new policy.

Comment: Both "the intent" and "vestige" mean something different than keeping a copy of the old one around.  If I completely rebuilt my car and ended up replacing all the parts except for a few, I could say that it's completely new with just a few vestiges of the old car in there.  For *intent* if the old policy was intended to prevent X from doing Y and the new policy did the same then the intent was maintained.

Comment: @jim, the idea isn't to keep a copy of the old policy around, but to put a, "WHEREAS the old policy was inadequate because reasons" statement in the new policy so people can better understand why the new policy was put in place.

Comment: @ShemSeger for "informational" purposes?

Comment: @ShemSeger- Ok, I see.  Then perhaps, "*Councillor [...] requested that, for historical perspective, a discussion of the old policy's inadequacies be included in the new policy wording.*"

Comment: I am not at all clear, such as you have described the position to us, on the legal status of the old policy. Indeed I am confused as to whether any of the old policy's provisions remain applicable. This matter would better be dealt with by a lawyer, in my view. Please do not place any reliance on anything I may have said.

Comment: Something like *informational purposes*, *as background*, *for reference*, *for comparison* would describe keeping old documents. But "Councillor [...] requested that the intent of the old policy be preserved in the new policy" doesn't actually mean that - it means keep the ethos, not the text.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps "*archival*" is appropriate here.

According to Webster's Dictionary:

> **Archival**, *adj.*
>   Pertaining to, or contained in, archives or records.

Answer (score 3):

Councillor [...] requested that the intent of the old policy be preserved in the new policy for **historical reference**...

> [**reference**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reference) - (noun)  the act of looking at or in something for information

Comment: Yeah - perhaps ***historical** reference*.

Comment: I would just say "for reference purposes". "Historical" isn't needed, because we already know these are old copies.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the word "posterity." and then omit the word "purposes". Posterity is typically used to express aspects of lineage; more specifically children or descendants. To record something for posterity means that it is present and evident for those who come after us. For that reason, I deduce that this is a proper use of the word "Posterity".

Comment: I used this word for work last week and then had a complete brain fog moment and couldn't remember it. Thank you. This is the best answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would say "for tracking purposes".

Comment: This would benefit from an explanation of how it answers the question since it seems the term was already considered in the question.  I encourage you to take the [tour] and see the [help], and welcome.